# Regex: How to capture multiple lines of contents

Tags: regex

When resolving git conflicts, I am trying to use regex to capture conflicts from source file, the content is like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    line1
    line2
    ... 
=======
```

This is my version:

```
^<<<<<<< HEAD\n\t.+\n\t.+\n\t=======\n\t
```

Obviously, my version only works for **fixed lines** because I need to repeat `.+\n\t` to match them. But really no idea of how to do this properly? Any tips?

[Update] I am using Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) engine from the Boost library.

Comment: try `(?ms)^<<<<<<< HEAD\n.*?\n\t*=======\n*\t*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems you miss the case when HEAD content is empty: <<<<<<< HEAD
=======

Comment: Sorry, you have only supplied one sample string with no specifications. That is all I could deduce. Please update the question with pertinent test cases. I do not know what an empty block looks like. Maybe `(?ms)^<<<<<<< HEAD.*?=======(?:\n|$)` is all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?sm)^<<<<<<< HEAD.*?\n\t*=======\n*\t*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE1nF3/1)

**Explanation**:

- `(?sm)` - inline modifiers: `s` makes the `.` match a newline as well as any other character and `m` makes the `^` match the line start and `$` match the line end
- `^` - start of the line
- `<<<<<<< HEAD` - a literal string `<<<<<<< HEAD`
- `.*?` - 0+ any characters, as few as possible, up to the first
- `\n\t*` - LF followed with 0+ tabs
- `=======` - a literal substring
- `\n*\t*` - (not sure you really need it) 0+ LFs followed with 0+ tabs.

Answer (score 0):

What language do you use ?
The option is allowing the "." to match new line along with ANY char, so that it matches multi line strings.

Adding this require the knowledge of the language in which you code.

Comment: Perl Compatible Regular Expressions， updated the question

Comment: You could comment that addressing me with `@`+ my username.